# Bernoulli Theorem Proof Doubt

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

[image]

In the wikipedia page when I was reading the proof of Bernoulli Theorem,
In the work done by pressure force why only work on two parts of fluid are considered?
Why mass displaced are equal the mass can also accumulate in the pipe right?
The page is there in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle

Comment: Mass accumulation violates incompressibility assumption for Bernoulli.

Comment: ok , then about the work done by pressure forces ?

Comment: @KyleKanos For steady state, it would also violate mass conservation.

Answer (score 0):

For a proof of Bernoulli theorem, we should go quite deep inside fluid mechanics.

Here we can try to provide a kind of qualitative proof for incompressible flows, applying the theorem of kinetic energy to a control volume $V_c$. Theorem of kinetic energy says that:

> The time derivative of the kinetic energy of a system equals the power of total forces acting on the system

Since $V_c$ is an open system that exchanges mass with the external environment through the surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$, we need to evaluate the flux through these surfaces. The theorem of kinetic energy for an open system reads

$\dfrac{d K}{dt} = \Phi_{S_1}(K) - \Phi_{S_2}(K) + P^{tot}$,

being $\Phi_{S_i}(K) = \dot{m}_i \frac{v_i^2}{2}$ the flux of the kinetic energy through the surface $S_i$, where $\dot{m}_i$ is the mass flux through the surface, namely $\dot{m}_i = \rho v_i A_i$, assuming uniform quantities on each section of the pipe.

Assuming that the total power exerted on the system through its boundary is only due to the pressure (neglecting viscous, dissipative stresses) on the boundary of the volume $V_c$ reads

$P_{S_i} = \pm v_i P_i A_i$,

with the sign $+$ on the inflow section $S_1$ where the pressure acts on the surface $S_1$ in the same direction of the velocity, $-$ on the outflow section $S_2$.

If we deal with a steady condition, $\frac{dK}{dt} = 0$, and $\dot{m}_1 = \dot{m}_2 = \dot{m}$ from the mass continuity,

$0 = \rho v_1 A_1 \dfrac{v_1^2}{2} - \rho v_2 A_2 \dfrac{v_2^2}{2} + v_1 P_1 A_1 - v_2 P_2 A_2$

$\rightarrow \qquad \underbrace{v_1 A_1}_{\dot{m}/\rho} \left[ \rho\dfrac{v_1^2}{2} + P_1 \right] = \underbrace{v_2 A_2}_{\dot{m}/\rho} \left[ \rho\dfrac{v_2^2}{2} + P_2 \right] $
$\rightarrow \qquad  \rho\dfrac{v_1^2}{2} + P_1 = \rho\dfrac{v_2^2}{2} + P_2$

The contribution of gravitational field can be obtained integrating the power along the trajectories of the fluid particles in the volume $V$. Integrating over the section of the stream-tube the elementary power $\delta \dot{W}_V$ done on a trajectory

$\displaystyle \dot{W}_V = \int_S \delta \dot{W}_V = \int_S \int_{\ell} \mathbf{v} \cdot \rho \mathbf{g} \ d \ell = \\ 
\quad \displaystyle = \int_S \int_{\tau} -v_z \rho g  \ v d t = - \rho g A v \int_{\tau} \dfrac{dz}{dt} dt = - \dot{m} g \Delta z = - v_2 A_2 \rho g z_2 + v_1 A_1 \rho g z_1$.